# Plugin for ShippingMethodManagement no longer called when upgrading from Magento 2 beta4 to 2.0.0 release

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I upgraded from the beta4 to the Magento 2.0.0 release.
Now, I plugin I defined is no longer executed.

My `app/code/Example/Product/etc/frontend/di.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
          <plugin name="forceJson" type="Example\Product\Controller\Checkout\Plugin" sortOrder="1"/>
      </type>
      <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart">
          <plugin name="forceJson" type="Example\Product\Controller\Checkout\Plugin" sortOrder="1"/>
      </type>
      <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface">
          <plugin name="allowEmptyQuotes" type="Example\Product\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement\Plugin" sortOrder="1"/>
      </type>
</config>
```

My `app/code/Example/Product/Model/Quote/ShippingMethodManagement/Plugin.php`

```
namespace Example\Product\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

class Plugin
{
      /**
       * Quote repository.
       *
       * @var QuoteRepository
       */
      protected $quoteRepository;

      /**
       * Shipping method converter
       *
       * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter
       */
      protected $converter;

      /**
       * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository Quote repository.
       */
      public function __construct(
          QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
          ShippingMethodConverter $converter
      ) {
          $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
          $this->converter = $converter;
      }

      /**
       * Allow empty quote for calculating the shipping methods / costs
       *
       * Plugin for: @see \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByAddress
       *
       * @param $subject
       * @param $result
       */
      public function aroundEstimateByAddress(
          \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement $subject,
          \Closure $proceed,
          $cartId,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface $address
      ) {
            // [...]
            xdebug_break(); // never called

      }
}
```

When I debug into
`\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement\Interceptor::estimateByAddress`, this function is called, but there `$pluginInfo` is null, so my plugin is not executed.

What change did I miss between beta4 and 2.0.0 ? My module does have a registration.php, and other parts of the module are loaded. If I put a syntax error in my `di.xml`, the Magento instance crashes as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, when I move my `di.xml` from `etc/frontend` to `etc/` in my module. Not sure why.

Comment: Yes,It is working fine